# On aurait pu aller + futur

Tags: conditionnel, futur

J'ignore si c'est une faute de français ou une conjugaison que je ne sais pas identifier, mais il m'arrive de faire la phrase suivante :

> Ah, tiens, on aurait pu aller à la piscine demain.

Évidemment, *on pourrait aller à la piscine demain* me semble plus simple/correct mais après un test en famille, personne n'a été choqué de la première formulation.

À quoi cela correspond-il ? Évidemment j'ai pensé au conditionnel mais je ne trouve pas de trace d'un conditionnel futur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La sens n'est pas le même:

> On pourrait aller à la piscine demain.

L'hypothèse se situe au présent, elle est ouverte : on ira peut-être à la piscine demain.

> On aurait pu aller à la piscine demain.

Il s'agit d'un conditionnel qui exprime un [irréel du passé](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/755.html). L'hypothèse se situe dans le passé et, telle qu'elle est exprimée, ne s'est pas réalisée (ne se réalisera pas). C'est à dire qu'on sait aujourd'hui qu'on n'ira pas ou du moins qu'on a pas prévu d'aller à la piscine **demain**. On y est peut-être déjà allé ou on y ira peut-être un autre jour...

Comment: Donc pour être correct, la phrase devrait avoir une autre partie, non ? Du genre : "*On aurait pu aller à la piscine demain, mais c'est ferié*" (où "*Si c'était pas ferié, ...*"). Sinon ce n'est pas un irréel du passé, je me trompe ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je ne pense pas que la phrase soit incorrecte. La proposition subordonnée conditionnelle n'a pas besoin d'être explicite, son existence est sous entendue ici.

Comment: C'est très intéressant. Je reformulerais un peu en disant "que l'on sait aujourd'hui que l'on a **pas prévu** d'aller a la piscine demain (parcequ'on a prévu d'aller au cinéma). Clairement, quand on me dit, ah tiens, on aurait pu aller a la piscine demain, ça signifie : ça te tente qu'on annule le cinéma et on va a la piscine à la place?)

Comment: Oui, influer sur le futur est plus envisageable qu'influer sur le passé ;-)